# Alternative way to change volume

Tags: iphone, ios, sound-volume

I have the volume + button broken, and if I click it, it may stuck itself and continuously increase the volume, so I avoid to use the + button. I tried the assistive touch, but it's incredibly annoying, sometimes I want to tap somewhere but I cannot because there is the icon in the middle, and I have to displace it all times.

I want an alternative way: is there a way to change the volume for example by changing it in options? I have iso 6, but also a solution for iso 7 is ok, I'll upgrade it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In iOS 6:

1. Double-tap the home button.
2. Swipe left-to-right twice and a volume slider appears there.

In iOS 7 and iOS 8:

1. Drag up from the bottom of the screen until Control Center appears.
2. The volume slider appears under the media controls.

Answer (score 2):

While this may not be what you are looking for as it requires buying new earphones...

I have a nice and reasonably priced, pair of Sony earbuds. They have a volume control right on the mic/pause button attached to the wire going to the left earbud.

Got mine at Target but they are available practically everywhere. I would imagine that other brands have this feature too. I've found that once you get used to having volume there most others come away as lacking...

Answer (score 1):

If jailbreaking is an option you can use Volume Amplifier

1. first you need to jailbreak using [evasion](https://mega.co.nz/#!gp9z2RTJ!VWcrCkGWqGp-0Ijk4mRQzE_ZdU1F0ojA5aKO7Ki7jo)
2. then download the link and wait...open and then plug you iphone and just click jailbreak...
3. wait until everything is ok...then you will see cydia then just search volume amplifier then install it
4. after intalation it will restart.....now you can max your volume to 200%

PS: If you download the evasion file you will see README.txt open it and just follow instructions and you are gonna be fine...I hope I help...dont worry this fine jus follow the instructions from the README.txt....